# Saving instructional results in R as a matrix or object

Tags: r, matrix, instructions

In the package CoinMinD I ran the GM function on the following code:

```
GM(c(2,4,5,1),0.05)
```

The results are as follows:

```
Original Intervals
Lower Limit
[1] 0.03470190 0.10880765 0.15542939 0.01035233
Upper Limit
[1] 0.5266663 0.6718765 0.7349127 0.4413580
Adjusted Intervals
Lower Limit
[1] 0.03470190 0.10880765 0.15542939 0.01035233
Upper Limit
[1] 0.5266663 0.6718765 0.7349127 0.4413580
Volume
[1] 0.06918613
```

I am trying to create a matrix where the first two lines Lower Limit and the Upper Limit, appear as follows:

```
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,]    0.03470190 0.5266663
[2,]    0.10880765 0.6718765
[3,]    0.15542939 0.7349127
[4,]    0.01035233 0.4413580
```

Unforunately, when I save the code to an object:

```
c<-GM(c(2,4,5,1),0.05)
```

and run

```
c[1]
```

or

```
GM(c(2,4,5,1),0.05) [1]
```

I only get the last line of the results:

```
> c[1]
[1] 0.06918613
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! Luckily the function `GM` is not a long one so we can look inside:

```
function (inpmat, alpha) 
{
    ## ... those lines for computing results are left out...
    cat("Original Intervals\n")
    cat("Lower Limit\n")
    print(GM.LL)
    cat("Upper Limit\n")
    print(GM.UL)
    cat("Adjusted Intervals\n")
    cat("Lower Limit\n")
    print(LLA)
    cat("Upper Limit\n")
    print(ULA)
    cat("Volume\n")
    print(VOL)
}
```

All values you want to extract are only printed rather than exported. We can easily modify this function to export them.

```
myGM <- function (inpmat, alpha) 
{
    k = length(inpmat)
    s = sum(inpmat)
    chi = qchisq(1 - (alpha/k), df = 1)
    pi = inpmat/s
    GM.UL = (chi + 2 * inpmat + sqrt(chi * chi + 4 * inpmat * 
        chi * (1 - pi)))/(2 * (chi + s))
    GM.LL = (chi + 2 * inpmat - sqrt(chi * chi + 4 * inpmat * 
        chi * (1 - pi)))/(2 * (chi + s))
    LLA = 0
    ULA = 0
    for (r in 1:length(inpmat)) {
        if (GM.LL[r] < 0) 
            LLA[r] = 0
        else LLA[r] = GM.LL[r]
        if (GM.UL[r] > 1) 
            ULA[r] = 1
        else ULA[r] = GM.UL[r]
    }
    diA = ULA - LLA
    VOL = round(prod(diA), 8)
    ## the lines for printing are removed
    ## replace it with the line below
    list(limit = matrix(c(GM.LL, GM.UL, LLA, ULA), ncol = 4L,
                        dimnames = list(NULL, c("ori_low", "ori_up", "adj_low", "adj_up"))),
         volume = VOL)
}

## test
myGM(c(2,4,5,1),0.05)

#$limit
#        ori_low    ori_up    adj_low    adj_up
#[1,] 0.03470190 0.5266663 0.03470190 0.5266663
#[2,] 0.10880765 0.6718765 0.10880765 0.6718765
#[3,] 0.15542939 0.7349127 0.15542939 0.7349127
#[4,] 0.01035233 0.4413580 0.01035233 0.4413580
#
#$volume
#[1] 0.06918613
```

You can easily extract the column you want from `$limit`.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, GM does only return the last value (Volume). All other values are simply printed on the console. You can catch them using `capture.output`, the get the values using `strsplit`:

```
library(CoinMinD)
cmd<-capture.output(GM(c(2,4,5,1),0.05) )
matrix(c(as.numeric(strsplit(cmd[3] , split=" ")[[1]][2:5]),
         as.numeric(strsplit(cmd[5] , split=" ")[[1]][2:5])), 
       nrow=4)

           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.03470190 0.5266663
[2,] 0.10880765 0.6718765
[3,] 0.15542939 0.7349127
[4,] 0.01035233 0.4413580
```